# FETCH_CLASS não seta valores de classe pai

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou usando o FETCH_CLASS para mapear as classes, só que quando por exemplo uma classe herda outra, o FETCH_CLASS não encontra os atributos da classe pai e acaba criando novos atributos

```
class UsuarioVO {

    private $id;
    private $nome;
    private $cidade;
    private $estado;
    private $bairro;
    private $cep;
    private $endereco;
    private $cpf;
    private $email;
    private $senha;

    function __construct() {

    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    function getCidade() {
        return $this->cidade;
    }

    function getEstado() {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    function getBairro() {
        return $this->bairro;
    }

    function getCep() {
        return $this->cep;
    }

    function getEndereco() {
        return $this->endereco;
    }

    function getCpf() {
        return $this->cpf;
    }

    function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    function getSenha() {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    function setCidade($cidade) {
        $this->cidade = $cidade;
    }

    function setEstado($estado) {
        $this->estado = $estado;
    }

    function setBairro($bairro) {
        $this->bairro = $bairro;
    }

    function setCep($cep) {
        $this->cep = $cep;
    }

    function setEndereco($endereco) {
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
    }

    function setCpf($cpf) {
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
    }

    function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    function setSenha($senha) {
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }

}


Class AlunoVO extends UsuarioVO {

    private $curso;
    private $turma;
    private $matricula;
    private $desconto_mensalidade;
    private $dia_vencimento;

    function __construct() {
        //parent::__construct();        
    }

    function getDia_vencimento() {
        return $this->dia_vencimento;
    }

    function setDia_vencimento($dia_vencimento) {
        $this->dia_vencimento = $dia_vencimento;
    }

    function getCurso() {
        return $this->curso;
    }

    function getTurma() {
        return $this->turma;
    }

    function getMatricula() {
        return $this->matricula;
    }

    function getDesconto_mensalidade() {
        return $this->desconto_mensalidade;
    }

    function setCurso($curso) {
        $this->curso = $curso;
    }

    function setTurma($turma) {
        $this->turma = $turma;
    }

    function setMatricula($matricula) {
        $this->matricula = $matricula;
    }

    function setDesconto_mensalidade($desconto_mensalidade) {
        $this->desconto_mensalidade = $desconto_mensalidade;
    }

}
```

O objeto vem assim:

```
        (
        [curso:AlunoVO:private] => Pedagogia
        [turma:AlunoVO:private] => 
        [matricula:AlunoVO:private] => 
        [desconto_mensalidade:AlunoVO:private] => 
        [dia_vencimento:AlunoVO:private] => 
        [id:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [nome:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [cidade:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [estado:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [bairro:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [cep:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [endereco:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [cpf:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [email:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [senha:UsuarioVO:private] => 
        [id] => 2
        [nome] => joão amaral da silva campos
        [document_cpf] => 05469464550
    )
```

Como resolvo isso?

Método que faz o uso das classes:

```
    function listarAlunos($curso = null) {

    try {
        if (!empty($curso)) {
            $listar_alunos = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.nome, c.nome AS curso, u.document_cpf  FROM usuarios u, matriculas m, cursos c, polos p WHERE (m.aluno = u.id) AND (m.curso = c.id) AND (c.polo = p.id) AND m.curso = :curso");
            $listar_alunos->bindValue(":curso", $curso);
        } else {
            $listar_alunos = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.nome, c.nome AS curso, u.document_cpf FROM usuarios u, matriculas m, cursos c, polos p WHERE (m.aluno = u.id) AND (m.curso = c.id) AND (c.polo = p.id)");
        }

        if(!$listar_alunos->execute()){
            throw new Exception($listar_alunos->errorInfo()[2]);
        }

        return $listar_alunos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "AlunoVO");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error ao listar alunos -> '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode editar e colocar o código que gerou esse problema?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta, da uma olhada lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples a sua `SQL` não traz os campos que são da sua classe base, observe, que eu alterei um pouco seu código e só tem discriminado os campos de 4 campos (`u.id, u.nome, c.nome AS curso, u.document_cpf`) e os outros, verifique:

```
function listarAlunos($curso = null) 
{

    $sql = " SELECT u.id, u.nome, c.nome AS curso, u.document_cpf ";
    $sql .= " FROM usuarios u, matriculas m, cursos c, polos p WHERE "; 
    $sql .= " (m.aluno = u.id) AND (m.curso = c.id) AND (c.polo = p.id) ";

    try {
        if (!empty($curso)) 
        {           
            $listar_alunos = $this->conexao->prepare($sql. " AND m.curso = :curso");
            $listar_alunos->bindValue(":curso", $curso);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $listar_alunos = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);
        }

        if(!$listar_alunos->execute()){
            throw new Exception($listar_alunos->errorInfo()[2]);
        }

        return $listar_alunos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "AlunoVO");

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Error ao listar alunos -> '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

então é só discriminar os campos que faltam na sua `SQL` para que a objeto dessa classe carregue corretamente os campos:

```
$sql = " SELECT u.id, u.nome, c.nome AS curso, u.document_cpf ";

// Incluir os campos que faltam, porque, sem eles acontece o problema
$sql .= "turma, matricula"; 

$sql .= " FROM usuarios u, matriculas m, cursos c, polos p WHERE "; 
$sql .= " (m.aluno = u.id) AND (m.curso = c.id) AND (c.polo = p.id) ";
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. Vi por ai que esse método não é confiável e que o correto seria usar uma ORM pronto, mas eu achei muito mais prático usar da forma como sei acima, você sabe me dizer algo sobre isso ou indica algum link que eu possa me informar melhor?

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos eu gosto da idéia ORM, mas tudo tem um preço e uma dosagem.  Eu uso hj mais ORM porque escrevo menos e mantenho padrão no meu código.